# Adobe Flash Builder and Serial Port/RS232 communication?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Could it be possible that I send data from COM4(Emulator GalaxyTab in windows system) via RS232 and could you please help me on example code thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an AIR native extension (ANE) that provides access to serial port/RS232:

https://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/

I use it, it works!

You can only use an ANE with an AIR project distributed in Native Installers (.exe, .dmg etc).